# UITextField does not display text correctly

Tags: ios, uitextfield, swift3

It's been bugging me for few hours.

UITextField fails to display **some** text although it has enough space to do it...When I rotate devise text miraculously appears!

*By the way it's not all text that I feed to the UITextField is treated the same. But there is no logical way to see if there is any obvious character that creates the issue.*

*see attached images:

[image]
[image]
Any ideas???

Comment: Use the View Debugger in Xcode to check what is happening to your constraints and views.

Comment: Maybe my description of the problem is not very good. The text field background color is the purple color you see. Sometimes the text appears correctly and sometimes is not. Same textfield, different text. BUT there is NOTHING different in the correct display apart from the fact that it is different text.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

1. Recreate uitextfield, sometimes storyboard can be quite buggy.
2. Make sure you have a proper size to show your text. for example try in a different page, make its edge to superview (page), see if the problem still occurs.
3. Try different text.

Comment: As i described in my question this does not happen with every text. At this point it seems random. Different text does not have the same issues BUT I have no idea what might the text difference be.